# --start-offset --end-offset usage in JMeterPluginsCMD.bat command

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to generate aggregate report using JMeterPluginsCMD.bat and exclude first 5 minutes(Warmup time) and last 5 minutes(Cool down time) from test results(jtl file)

Can you please let me know how we can use --start-offset  --end-offset in JMeterPluginsCMD.bat to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/#Usage-and-Parameters)

> `--start-offset <sec>` include in report only samples with (timestamp - relativeStartTime) > startOffset
>
> `--end-offset <sec>`   include in report only samples with (timestamp - relativeStartTime) < endOffset

So the command should be something like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv AggregateReport.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/result.jtl --start-offset 300 --end-offset 300 --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

You may have to install [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) as well.

More information: [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

Comment: I have tried this but it does not give expected result,  is there any way to debug or check if first 5 minutes and last 5 minutes samples are excluded from jtl file.

Comment: The first column of the .jtl file is sampler start time in milliseconds since beginning of Unix epoch